# Reference existing object in procedural PHP in a function argument

Tags: php, mysqli

Let us have the following code:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("hostname", "user", "password", "database");

function close () {
    $mysqli->close();
    die;
}
```

This will not work, because $mysqli object is not referenced in the argument of the function close(). Is it possible to reference this object without modifying the argument list (which is no arguments)? Let's assume for the sake of this problem that I cannot put the $mysqli as an argument to close() and I have to reference it in another fashion. Can this be done?

Thank you.

EDIT: This is procedural PHP even though I used the object-oriented mysqli. There are no classes in my code.

Comment: Add `global $mysqli;` inside the `close()`.

Comment: Without using globals? Can I make a pointer like in C/C++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options if you want to stick with the procedural functions:

1.

```
 function close($mysqli) {
   $mysqli->close();
   die; // This probably shouldn't be here.
  }
```

2.

```
function close() {
  global $mysqli;
  $mysqli->close();
  die; // This probably shouldn't be here.
}
```

Comment: So I absolutely have to use globals? I can't make a pointer similar to C/C++?

Comment: You are only changing the scope of the variable, not creating a new one. You're still using the same reference

Answer (score 0):

```
function close () {
    $GLOBALS['mysqli']->close();
    die;
}
```